# Javascript variable value in page source for seo from Drupal.settings

Tags: javascript

Declared a variable in settings.php

```
$conf['my-variable'] ="my-variable-value";
```

Added inline javascript

```
drupal_add_js("array('my-variable'=>variable_get('my-variable'))");
```

Need to print variable values from Drupal.setttings in inline js

```
drupal_add_js("jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  window.my-val = Drupal.settings.my-variable;

})",'inline');
```

So the output on page is comming up like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.my-val =Drupal.settings.my-variable; 
</script>
```

But I need it should be like below for seo requirement

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.my-val = "my-variable-value";
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're over-estimating the potential SEO value of making such a change, but if you don't want to use Drupal settings you can just interpolate the value into a static string and use that:

```
$var = variable_get('my-variable');
$js = <<<EOF
function() { 
  window['my-val'] = '{$var}';
}
EOF;
drupal_add_js($js, 'inline');
```

I'll leave data-sanitising up to you, how far you need to go will depend on the source of the variable.

Comment: Thanks, a lot for reply , let me check if it would work.